# xdocument create from scratch

Tags: foreach, linq-to-xml, nullreferenceexception

Noobie to the XML/Xdocument world. 
Trying to create an Xdocument with a variable number of DataField elements which are passed in as a List of Tuples.
This document is used as part of an API call to edit fields in a record on a distant server.
When I try to add the DataField elements in the foreach loop, xdoc is seen as Null.  So I keep getting NullReferenceException errors.
Why does xdoc or its XElements = null when I just created it?
I know this isn't a difficult situation, but for the last few days I've looked through several sites 
and it is clear I am not getting something very fundamental.

```
public XDocument MakeXDoc(string frmID, string prj, List<Tuple<string, string, string>> frmdata)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://xxxxxxx.yyyyyy.com/api/v1/";
    var xdoc = new XDocument(
         new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
         new XElement(ns + "ProjectDataRequest",
         new XElement(ns + "Project",
         new XElement(ns + "DataFields", new XAttribute("ProjectId", prj), new XAttribute("FormId", frmID),
         new XElement(ns + "DataField" , new XAttribute("DataFieldId", ""), new XAttribute("Value", "") )))));

        foreach (Tuple<string, string, string> fld in frmdata)
        {
            XElement xdf = new XElement(ns + "DataField", new XAttribute("DataFieldId", fld.Item1.ToString()), new XAttribute("Value", fld.Item3.ToString()));
            xdoc.Element(ns + "DataField").Add(xdf);
        }

    return xdoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throws the exception, because there isn't an element yet. To build the wanted XML, you could use LINQ's `Select`:

```
XDocument MakeXDoc(string frmID, string prj, List<Tuple<string, string, string>> frmdata)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://xxxxxxx.yyyyyy.com/api/v1/";
    var xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
        new XElement(ns + "ProjectDataRequest",
        new XElement(ns + "Project",
        new XElement(ns + "DataFields", new XAttribute("ProjectId", prj), new XAttribute("FormId", frmID),
        frmdata.Select(d => new XElement(ns + "DataField", new XAttribute("DataFieldId", d.Item1), new XAttribute("Value", d.Item3)))))));

    return xdoc;
}
```

It adds a new `DataField` element for each item in `frmdata` as child of `DataFields`.